# input関数でEOFError

Tags: python, python3, visual-studio

### 前提・実現したいこと

Pythonのエラーメッセージの意味がわからず困っております。
初心者質問で恐縮ですが、お助けください。

---

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

`chap2.py` というプログラムの `input` 関数「入力してください：」に「もうやめたい」と入力すると、以下のようにターミナルに表示されます。

```sh
入力してください:もうやめたい
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chap2.py", line 2, in <module>
    parrot = input("入力してください:")
EOFError
```

---

### 該当のソースコード

Python 3.7.3で次のように入力しました。

```
parrot = input("入力してください:")
print(parrot)
)
```

---

### 試したこと

デフォルト設定で文字化けしたので、ターミナルの文字コードは utf-8 に変更しています。
Active code page: 65001

`terminal integrated shell args windows` の `Edit in setting json` で、以下コードを追記しました。

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
"-NoExit",
"chcp",
"65001"
],
```

該当フォルダからコマンドプロンプト立ち上げ、そこからも試しましたが同様のエラーメッセージが出てしまいます。

とても困っています。何卒ご指南の程、よろしくお願い致します。

---

### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

- Windows7

Comment: マルチポスト先: [https://teratail.com/questions/187898](https://teratail.com/questions/187898)

Comment: > `該当のソースコード` の部分を確認すると、閉じ括弧が多く、このまま実行すると `SyntaxError` という文法上のエラーが発生します。実際に実行したコードはこの通りでしょうか？また、 visual-studio のタグがついておりますが、実行環境はVisual Studio上のターミナルということでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

マルチポスト先で解決されたようなので転載します。

> python3.Xをインストールし、それに則ってプログラムを記載していたのですが、
> その前にインストールして使っていたpyothon2.7がVSCに認識されていて、2.7で動いてたために3.Xのプログラムがエラーになっていました。
> pyothon2.7をアンインストールしたら解決しました。

※VSC = Visual Studio Code